# RcmdrMisc could not be loaded

Tags: r

I successfully installed and ran Rcmdr on my Windows 8.1 laptop. After a couple days (with it being turned on and off repeatedly), I tried running library(Rcmdr) and got the following error

> Loading required package: splines
>
> Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
>
> Loading required package: car
>
> Loading required package: sandwich
>
> Error in readRDS(pfile): unknown input format
>
> Error: package 'RcmdrMisc' could not be loaded
>
> Running traceback() shows:
>
> 3: stop(gettextf("package %s could not be loaded", sQuote(pkg)), call,
>   = FALSE, domain = NA)
>
> 2: getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
>
> 1:library(Rcmdr)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Install the RcmdrMisc package as well. The R commander needs htmlTable package as well. Hence, installing the packages

RcmdrMisc
htmlTable

Should resolve the issue

Comment: You may add a link to the package or any documentation.